# Google complains image missing or invalid itemtype

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

No matter how I mark up the image, Google complains that the image is either missing or has an invalid itemtype.

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
 <head>
  ...
  <link itemprop="image" href="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <img itemprop="image" src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I add an image to an article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org’s [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) can have a URL (this is what you do) or an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) as value.

For [Google’s Articles Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles), Google seems (according to their documentation and their testing tool) to support only the variant with `ImageObject`.

So if you want to get that Rich Snippet, you might have to use something like this instead:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="url" src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
    <meta itemprop="height" content="20" />
    <meta itemprop="width" content="20" />
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but just replaced `body` with `html` and google still says the image is missing and that it is required.

Comment: @user3338098: If I copy-paste my snippet (or if I replace `body` with `html` in my snippet) and test it, no `image` related error is reported.

Comment: we use angularjs, but google can only see what's inside the noscript tag, since emulating the whole body of the page in a noscript tag is very expensive we have to cache the results for several days which is why the itemprop is not seen by google, because it's seeing a version that is several days old.

Comment: @user3338098: Note that using JSON-LD (instead of Microdata or RDFa) might make more sense in this context, because you don’t need to use HTML as a "carrier".

Comment: Stumbled across the same thing. Very confusing, since [their own examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product#microdata_1) also just use `<link itemprop="image" href="…" />`